# Trim Macro errors when rows went from 40,000 to 90,000

Tags: arrays, excel, trim, vba

The below Macro work with 40,000 rows of data but errors (1004) when I updated to a new sheet with 90,000 rows (by the end of the project will have about 200,000 rows)

Not sure why I am getting this error, am I hitting some kind of built in limitation? (90,000 row does not seem ovorly large)

Thank you

```
Sub TrimAllSheetsAM()
Dim arrData() As Variant, arrReturnData() As Variant
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

With ActiveSheet.Cells
       lCols = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
       lRows = .Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

For Each wsh In Worksheets(Array("LI_Data_Resent", "RegistrationData_Resent"))
With wsh

 Application.StatusBar = "Processing TRIM Worksheets " & .Name & "..."

  ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
  ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

  Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(lRows, lCols)
  arrData = rng.Value

  For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRows

    On Error Resume Next
      arrReturnData(i, j) = Trim(arrData(i, j))
    On Error GoTo 0

    Next i
  Next j

  rng.Value = arrReturnData

  Set rng = Nothing

  End With
  Next wsh

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked MS Docs to the maximum size of an array of Variant? Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: Sorry about that the line is `rng.Value = arrReturnData` I am using Arrays every where and this is the only one throwing a error

Comment: My only option here is a guess: Have you looked at the data to ensure there's nothing 'weird' in there (somewhere between rows 40,001 & 90,000)? Do you have another data set you can test on? Maybe increase the data by 1-2,000 rows at a time until it errors - that would narrow where the error might be.

Comment: Thanks for the imput FreeMan, I will try marching through the extra rows

Comment: To test size vs. data, you could split the number of rows/columns into batches and do it at a size that you know works (e.g. batches of 40,000).  Also, how many columns are in play?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables i and j as Long: `Dim i as Long, j as Long` to accomodate rows and/or columns beyond 65535.
This is a common mistake which could be avoided with a `Option Explicit` statement at the very beginning of the module (been there, done that).

Comment: Great idea, and I thought that was it. Unfortunately, he has already declared them so...

Comment: Oops, my mistake, sorry. I find the on-off switching of the error handler unnecessary effort. Could you try `if istext(arrData(i,j) then arrData(i,j) = Trim(arrData(i,j)) end if` instead? You notice that this will work on the array you copied the cell values to. No need for `arrReturnData` thus saving 50% of allocated memory. Might well be a memory issue.